# Enable SSL (two way handshake) in web application in tomcat to external application

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl-certificate

How can i enable SSL (two way handshake) in web application in tomcat to external application. I searched in google. But it gives a way to enable SSL between tomcat and client. But i need to enable SSL between Web app to external application (the application in tomcat calls an another rest web service). How can i do that?

**EDIT**
I know that we can consider that the web app as a client and external application as the server and then we can enable SSL. But i need to find a way to configure it in Tomcat. In here the external Application means, .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no way to do it in tomcat level. I could enable it in the application (in the server) level. I used [this link](http://www.stefanocapitanio.com/configuring-two-way-authentication-ssl-with-apache/) to do that.